# How can I redirect page to next page without click automatically?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to make users go to next page after 10 seconds not immediately

My code below

```
<div class="col-md-<?= $col_num ?>">
        <?= $this->Flash->render() ?>

        <?= $this->Form->create(null, ['id' => '']); ?>
        <?= $this->Form->hidden('action', ['value' => 'continue']); ?>
        <?= $this->Form->hidden('page', ['value' => $page + 1]); ?>
        <?= $this->Form->button(__('Click here to continue - Step (1/2)'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary',]); ?>
        <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
    </div>
```

Go to next page immediately ( code )

```
<script>
var buttonElement = document.querySelector('.btn.btn-primary');
if (buttonElement) {
    buttonElement.click();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use **setTimeout** function in JS

[Offical Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)

So Change this block

```
if (buttonElement) {
    buttonElement.click();
}
```

to

```
if (buttonElement) {

  setTimeout(() => {
    buttonElement.click();
  }, 10000);

}
```

Comment: Passing strings to `setTimeout` is really not a good idea.

Comment: Good feedback, my answer amended. Thanks